# Microsoft Edge User Data Default Folder

Tags: directory, download, microsoft-edge

It might be a weird question, but does anyone know where I could find the default Microsoft Edge **User Data** folder to **download**?

Comment: Assuming you mean how to find it programmatically in a certain programming language: there are `Win32API` functions like `SHGetSpecialFolderPathA` and certain `CSIDL` folder constants: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderpatha

Comment: You can find your default profile/User Data folder in edge://version. Would you please explain your question with more details?

Comment: I want to download the "User Data" folder the way it comes as soon as we install Edge, if I open Edge, enter a website and close Edge, it will add several files to the "User Data", I wanted to download it from standard version, without any site cache and etc.

Comment: Well, I think you can download/backup your "User Data" folder as soon as you install Edge. Just close it (if it prompts) without clicking on anything in the browser and go to `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data`.